# Set the initial "current" time in PHP

Tags: php, date, time

I'm having an application in PHP which I want to foresight how it works in certain situations which I need to rewind the time to the future. 
Is there any ways to do this?

I could only find timezone function which let me change the time zone but what I want us to change it to the future like... 3weeks or something like that.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, and why they didn't work

Comment: "Rewind the time to the future". Mind blown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways to do this with PHP. Here's one:

```
$future = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+3 weeks"));
```

Here's another:

```
$future = (new DateTime())->modify("+3 weeks")->format("Y-m-d");
```

Here's another:

```
$future = (new DateTime())->add(new DateInterval("P21D"))->format("Y-m-d");
```

Comment: Thanks. I just had a quick thought about your code plugged into my app so I'll do a test run. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for [fluxcapacitor](https://github.com/majek/fluxcapacitor) if you're running on Linux

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with

```
date('l jS F (Y-m-d)', strtotime('3 week'));
```

or

```
date('l jS F (Y-m-d)', strtotime('21 days')); // for future 3 weeks
```